Need a SOQL query to retrieve files from Case object
The UI shows multiple documents associated with a Case.  I am attempting to write a query to extract the documents. The query below is not pulling any results back.
SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = (id of Case record)


where do you run this query, is it a dev console? make sure, that those files are shared for a user, that is executing a query

If you want to find the files attached to the case you can use the below query.

SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId  FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId = '5000xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND LinkedEntity.Type
= 'Case'

In the above query, ContentDocumentId is the ID of the files and LinkedEntityId is the ID of the case.
